# add_field logstash after converting value to Json

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I have logfile containing log in this form

```
"{\"user_id\":\"79\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-12-28T11:10:26Z\"‌​,\"operation\":\"ver‌​3 - Requested for recommended,verified handle information\",\"data\":\"\",\"content_id\":\"\",\"channel_id‌​\":\"\"}"
```

for which I have written logstash configuration

```
input {
beats {
    port => "5043"
}
}
filter{
    grok {
       match => { "message" => "%{QS:mydata}"}
    }
    json {
       source => "message"
       target => "parsedJson"
    }
    mutate {
       add_field =>{
        "user_id" => "%{[parsedJson.user_id]}"
        "operation" => "%{[parsedJson][operation]}"
        "data"=> "%{[parsedJson][operation]}"
       }
     }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
       hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    }
}
```

basically I have tried many permutations to fetch the value but in elasticsearch data is like the image below. I am not able to fetch data from JSON and assign to a new value.
please help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What if you try including the `add_field` within your `json` filter and make `mydata` as your `source` in `json`. Also please make sure that you don't separate the `add_field` value with the `.` dot:

```
json {
     source => "mydata"
     target => "parsedJson"
     add_field => {
      "user_id" => "%{[parsedJson][user_id]}}"
      "operation" => "%{[parsedJson][operation]}}"
      "data" => "%{[parsedJson][data]}}"
     }
     remove_field=>["mydata"] <-- you can ignore this if you really don't want to remove
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: operation     %{[parsedJson][operation]}}
 user_id     %{[parsedJson][user_id]}}

these values is not getting parsed which I am fetching from parsedJson

Comment: @YatenderSingh hi i've updated the answer, what if you try adding the field within the `json` filter itself? Have a look at this [thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/accessing-field-of-json-input/56068) as well.

Comment: one thing to observe is that when I am just adding reference of parsedJson to any new field it is fetching it's value 

user_id     {"user_id":"79","timestamp":"2016-12-28T11:10:26Z"‌​,"operation":"ver‌​3 - Requested for recommended,verified handle information","data":"","content_id":"","channel_id‌​":""}


but when I m trying to fetch the value inside parsedJson it is not fetching and setting it's value as string.

Comment: I tried to run and use event api using though ruby code .. but it is also not able to fetch key value of a JSON object. don't know what is wrong.